# start MySQL server automatically with application start

Tags: mysql, c#, xampp

How can I start MySQL server automatically with C# WPF application start?
I am using xampp. I want to start xampp and then MySQL automatically when the app starts, how to achieve it?
I tried this:

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController();

            controller.MachineName = ".";
            controller.ServiceName = "mysql";

            // Start the service
            controller.Start();
```

but it is not working as it says that mysql service does not exists.

Comment: How did you determine the service name?

Comment: I found it in xampp app service settings, but dont know if it is correct.
Is there a way I can start the xampp and mysql automatically? So the user does not need to start xampp each time on his own.

Comment: Well then may be you should verify the service name by looking at the list of services your OS knows about.

Comment: you don't need the service, you can start mysqld with a config file

Comment: yes I found out finally, thanks
but now there needs to be hard coded path